# .NET ASMX WebService and external class to be called by Client

Tags: .net, asmx

I have a ASMX vb.net service that references an external (I cannot modify it) .net dll library (named RTS) where class TEST is defined (with properties and methods). HelloWorld method of my ASMX accepts as parameter TEST class byval.
Well, I've created the related client that consumes the ASMX.
The client as well references the same .net dll library (named RTS) where class TEST is defined.
When I write call from client to HelloWorld method, the requested parameter is ServiceReference1.TEST type insted of RTS.TEST and this is not so good to me because I cannot see any method in ServiceReference1.TEST class.
Is it possible to say to the WebService to use RTS.TEST class so the client can use it?
Thank You

```
external dll RTS 
Class TEST {...} 
WebService
function HelloWorld (byval X as RTS.TEST) 

Client 
private ToService as new ServiceReference1.ServiceSoapClient
... 
dim P as new RTS.TEST
ToService.HelloWorld(P) -> throws error: cannot convert TEST to TEST 
That's because HelloWorld in the client accepts ServiceReference1.TEST type instead of RTS.TEST type
```

Comment: Web Services usually exchange documents (properties only) and not objects (including methods). If you want to create a TEST instance on the service side with the same properties as the data contract sent by the client, you have to copy them from the received data contract to a new RTS.TEST instance.

Comment: I've been not so clear ;( external dll RTS Class TEST {...} WebService function HelloWorld (byval X as RTS.TEST) ---- Client private ToService as new ServiceReference1.ServiceSoapClient ... dim P as new RTS.TEST ToService.HelloWorld(P) -> throws error: cannot convert TEST to TEST That's because HelloWorld in the client accepts ServiceReference1.TEST type instead of RTS.TEST type –

Comment: Please copy your code to your question

Comment: ok I done the update

Comment: The client serializes its TEST instance (typically to Json, Soap...), when the service receives the serialized document, it deserializes it to a `ServiceReference1.TEST` instance. You have to convert the `ServiceReference1.TEST` instance to a `RTS.TEST` instance in your operations.

Comment: ok I guessed it, but how to do it in an automatic way?

Comment: There's no way to do that automatically since you don't own `RTS.TEST` and even if you did, having separated classes for service contracts greatly helps decoupling service entities from data/business entities.